# Connection refused from Ubuntu VM to Snappy Ubuntu Core VM

Tags: ssh, vmware, ubuntu-core

My objective is to learn building and deploying Snappy packages/apps to Snappy Ubuntu Core platform.

For this on my MacBook Pro, using VMware Fusion virtualisation tool I set up two virtual machines; one with Ubuntu platform and the other one with Snappy Ubuntu Core platform.

I can ping any VM from the other one using their VMware assigned static IP addresses without  problem.

I have been following the simple example given here:
https://developer.ubuntu.com/en/snappy/

Everything worked up to the point when I executed this command from hello-world sample package folder on my Ubuntu VM, in order to install the sample package on Ubuntu Core:

```
snappy-remote --url=ssh://xxx.xx.xxx.xxx:8022 install ./hello-world_1.0.5_all.snap
```

where xxx.xx.xxx.xxx is the IP address of the snappy.

The error I received is this:

```
Installing ./hello-world_1.0.5_all.snap from local environment
issues while running ssh command: ssh: connect to host xxx.xx.xxx.xxx port 8022: Connection refused
lost connection
```

I have been wrestling with SSH setup on the Snappy Ubuntu Core VM without much success in the past 5 hours. Any tip, idea is welcome.

Many thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had the same issue and did the following to solve the problem

```
cd
sudo mv /etc/ssh/sshd_not_to_be_run .
sudo service ssh start
```

Comment: can you explain what this does?